# How to inherit and modify nv.d3.js javascript file from web module odoo 10

Tags: javascript, inheritance, odoo-10

I am using Odoo 10. Trying to inherit and modify nv.d3.js file in web module but no effect and no error is showing. Please check what I am doing wrong here.

my .js file:

```
odoo.define('budget_management.graph', function(require){
"use strict";
var WebClient = require('web.nv.d3');
var Model = require('web.Model');
var utils = require('web.utils');
WebClient.contentGenerator.include({
trowEnter.append("td")
    .classed("value",true)
    .html(function(p, i) {
var myval = valueFormatter(p.value, i)
//alert(myval)
return myval+'%'
});

var html = table.node().outerHTML;
if (d.footer !== undefined)
    html += "<div class='footer'>" + d.footer + "</div>";
return html;
});
});
```

And my xml file contains:

```
<template id="assets_backend" name="extend_web_nvd3js assets" inherit_id="web.assets_backend"> 
   <xpath expr="." position="inside"> 
       <script type="text/javascript" src="/budget_management/static/src/js/inherit.nv.d3.js"></script> 
   </xpath>
</template>
```

if I change the code from the core module it is working but unable to inherit and implement this.

Comment: First of all have you checked weather your file is actually inherited or not via browser console, if it is there then check your variable 'var webclient' contain any data or not.

Comment: I checked the console, it is empty. Also I tried alert but no popup. So it is not reaching the javascript file itself.

Comment: If your alert is not pop up than you need to check file name and relevant preferences. Like file path in xml and xml file in manifes, etc.